# Javascript element.offsetLeft and element.getBoundingClientRect().left difference

Tags: javascript, position

Lets say we have following html element:

```js
let main = document.getElementById('main');

console.log(main.offsetLeft);
console.log(main.getBoundingClientRect().left);
```

```css
#main{
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

</div>
```

appended to `document.body`. I want to get upper left coordinate of div, relative to document. So I use `element.offsetLeft` property, which should return left coordinates of element relative to `offsetParent` (which in this case should be document.body). Then to compare I get `element.getBoundingClientRect().left` property, which should return its left position relative to view port. Page isn't scrolled so I thought results should be the same, but I got totally different values. Why?

JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/6h9r5keo/

Comment: hint: `transform: translate(-50%, 50%)`

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks! Post answer if you want, I'll accept it.

Comment: Looks like offsetLeft doesn't consider CSS transforms, but I can't find a proof in spec.

Comment: Yes I figured it out already (thanks to your hint). I meant, if you want, post official answer and I'll accept it so you will get points.

Comment: @dfsq Please post this as a complete answer! This question has been viewed 271 times, that's hundreds of people looking to understand this, myself included :)